# How to Create a New Variable Based on a List on Vector

Tags: r

In R,

With

a) list containing regions (Northeast, South, North Central, West) that each state belongs to

```
regions <- list(
    west = c("WA", "OR", "CA", "NV", "AZ", "ID", "MT", "WY",
                     "CO", "NM", "UT"),
    south = c("TX", "OK", "AR", "LA", "MS", "AL", "TN", "KY",
                        "GA", "FL", "SC", "NC", "VA", "WV"),
    midwest = c("KS", "NE", "SD", "ND", "MN", "MO", "IA", "IL",
                            "IN", "MI", "WI", "OH"),
    northeast = c("ME", "NH", "NY", "MA", "RI", "VT", "PA", 
                                "NJ", "CT", "DE", "MD", "DC")
)
```

And
b) a data.frame with States and Deaths

```
#A tibble:

  state      Deaths 
  <chr>          <int>    
1 AL             29549      
2 AK               741      
3 AR             50127   
4 NJ            15142   
5 CA            175213   
6 IA            1647   
...
```

I want to create a new variable, matching each state to it's region and summarizing Deaths. What's the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 2):

We may `stack` the `list` to a two column data.frame and  do a join

```
library(dplyr)
stack(regions)  %>%
   left_join(df1, ., by = c("state" = "values")) %>%
   rename(region = 'ind')
```

-output

```
   state Deaths    region
1    AL  29549     south
2    AK    741      <NA>
3    AR  50127     south
4    NJ  15142 northeast
5    CA 175213      west
6    IA   1647   midwest
```

If the `df1` have duplicate rows, we may do a group by `summarise`

```
stack(regions)  %>%
   left_join(df1, ., by = c("state" = "values")) %>%
   group_by(state, region = 'ind') %>%
   summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(state = c("AL", "AK", "AR", "NJ", "CA", "IA"), 
    Deaths = c(29549L, 741L, 50127L, 15142L, 175213L, 1647L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
What I did here was just create the list into a data frame with one column denoting the region and the other a list of states

[image]

Here I used a dplyr function "right_join" which will "line up" the different rows and columns based on specific values. So here we want to line up the corresponding region based on states.